# How to create new bucketed column from an existing continuous column in SQL?

Tags: sql, bucket, discrete

I have the following my_table in SQL with one numeric column:

```
Age
---
31
53
52
37
57
19
20
63
59
```

I want to have a new column in the table with range buckets along the following:
"`Young`": 0-30
"`MidAge`": 31-50
"`Old`": 51-

So the expected result:

```
Age AgeGroup
------------
31  MidAge
53  Old
52  Old
37  MidAge
57  Old
19  Young
20  Young
63  Old
59  Old
```

How can I solve it with SQL?

Comment: please see this link.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `CASE` expression here:

```sql
SELECT Age, CASE WHEN Age <= 30 THEN 'Young'
                 WHEN Age <= 50 THEN 'MidAge'
                                ELSE 'Old'
            END AS AgeGroup
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to specify your age ranges

```
SELECT Age, CASE    
                    WHEN Age BETWEEN 0 and 30 THEN 'Young'
                    WHEN Age BETWEEN 31 and 50 THEN 'MidAge'
                    WHEN Age > 50 THEN 'Old'
                    ELSE 'Unknown'
            END AS AgeGroup
FROM yourTable;
```

The else part will carter for odd situations incase someone enters a negative value in database